# How to really completely uninstall visual studio?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, visual-studio

I am trying to make the computer as close as possible as if Visual Studio would have never been installed on it. I used its own installer to remove all the Installed components. Then I went to Apps and features and uninstalled visual studio from there as well.

Then I read the official documentation about [Removing Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) where it says that I should run `installCleanup.exe -f`, which I did, with the exception that on my computer I found it under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.**98e8da4d2c7a4d1aa6e0d6e8ca2a3a02**\resources\app\layout\installCleanup.exe

The above file still exists on my computer and it obviously came from the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer. It's in the name. Can I just delete it, together with the entire `Microsoft Visual Studio` folder? What else should I delete to really completely uninstall Visual Studio? Are there perhaps also registries left behind that should go away? Where can I find some documentation about it?

A search on my computer revealed the following folders that may or may not be there because I ever installed Visual Studio:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\myotheruser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Visual Studio Setup
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Visual Studio 2019
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Visual Studio 2019Templates
C:\Windows\System32\Tasks_Migrated\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTA\AppInfoDocument\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.AppInfoDocument
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Adapter.v9.0
```

Then a bunch of others really similar to the ones above, so I would assume I can do to them the same thing.

This question is not a duplicate, as I'm not trying to fix some issue with Visual Studio by uninstalling it. My computer runs properly. I just want Visual Studio gone. No other questions specifically ask about what else can be removed after `installCleanup.exe -f` already run.

Comment: What's your practical reason trying to remove it completely? Other apps might also depend on visual studio components, so deleting everything manually might broke them. If this is really a concern for you, then the best option is to reinstall your pc.

Comment: What could depend on ```InstallCleanup.exe```? It sucks if the only way to uninstall Visual Studio is to reinstall the OS, but if it gets confirmed as such, then it's a case of mumbling a swear at Microsoft, and then moving on. I suppose what you call Visual Studio components that may be required by other software were installed by that other software. Otherwise the other software wouldn't work. Making the PC as if Visual Studio was never installed would not include removing components that existed before the installation of Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot manually delete the folders?  All of those are user generated which is the reason the uninstaller isn’t removing them. One might want to uninstall Visual Studio but keep their projects

Comment: I don't think ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio``` is user generated. There is no other reason to not delete these folders, which are not user generated, other than that I want to be cautious before breaking things.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know specifically about Visual Studio, but I suggest using a tool like [Revo uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com). It lets you use the provided uninstaller and searches for files to cleanup afterwards. You'd have to have the program installed, though.

Comment: I tried to use it after I uninstalled it, and didn't find anything. Maybe reinstalling and then using revo uninstaller would work, but I'd obviously prefer if there would be something that doesn't require me to install Visual Studio, in order to uninstall it.